# Change meta tags programatically

Tags: functions, post-meta, actions, facebook, wp-head

Is there a way to change the meta tags not in the head but in a template file through code?

I would like to change the meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="description" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

They are automatically set when calling the facebook SDK. Is there a way to change these tags in my code (not in header.php)?

I've tried to do this in my child template (*content-share.php*):

```
<?php
   add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_meta_tags' , 10 );
?>
```

And then in functions.php of my theme I have:

```
function add_meta_tags() {
    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="Test">' . "\n";
}
```

But that doesn't do anything. Also when I add a `die;` in the function nothing changes. It's like my function isn't called.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot remove tags in this manner. Find an action name plugin uses to add these and do `remove_action` on those.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do the `add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_meta_tags' , 10 );` in your functions.php instead of the template to get the function called. And it adds it then everywhere where you have `wp_head()`. So if you want to only call it content-share.php you need some conditioning logic like

```
if (is_page_template('page-templates/content-share.php')) {
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_meta_tags' , 10 );
}
```

Of course change the page-templates folder to be what ever the folder is where you have the template in your theme folder.

Comment: My function is called now, he adds the meta tag. But the other one is still in my head. How can I remove it first?

Comment: Do you have those meta tags set in the header.php? Or where does the others come from? Does some plugin insert those, and if so, you should check the support for the plugin in question.

Comment: I think the tags are added by the "WordPress SEO by Yoast" plugin.

Comment: edit: nope. Can't you disable the facebook meta from outputting through the plugin in the plugin options? another edit: someone said this on the forums `global $wpseo_og, $wpseo_twitter;
remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $wpseo_og, 'opengraph' ), 30 );
remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( $wpseo_twitter, 'twitter' ), 40 );`